# How to create a video from an animating UIView in iOS (Swift / ObjC)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, avfoundation

I've looked around and couldn't find any solution for this...

My goal is to create a video on iOS from an UIViewController who has some animating subviews. Some people create images frame to frame from this ViewController for e.g. 20 seconds and compose them into a video with Apple's AVFoundation.

I don't think this is an optimal solution, not only because of the performance but also because the enduser who wants to render a video has to wait at least 20 seconds until every frame is captured (assumed that the video only contains 1 frame / second).

**Is there any other possible solution to achieve that – maybe in the background and much faster?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, you are not going to be able to create something that works faster than the lossy hardware h.264 video encoder available in iOS. There are other ways to capture and compress whole frames as lossless video frames, but it is not going to be faster since you would still need to wait for all the IO to finish.